# C# - Must be misunderstanding something about static

Tags: c#, static

got this little line of code.
when I run it, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the line "Roads_Vertices[i, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(Coordinates[0]);".
Help !

Thanks
Gabriel

```
namespace RouteSim
{
static class Program
{
    static double[,] Roads_Vertices;
    static double[,] Roads_Segments;

    static void Main()
    {
        // Declarations and Initializations
        // Read Roads from XML
        Parse_Road_Data();

        // User Interface
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form_MainWindow());
    }

    static void Parse_Road_Data()
    {
        // Reads and parses the Roads XML file
        XmlDocument Road_File = new XmlDocument();
        Road_File.Load(@"D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RouteSim\Additional Data\Roads.xml");

        XmlNodeList Road_Vertices_NodeList = Road_File.GetElementsByTagName("Road_Vertex");
        for (int i = 0; i < Road_Vertices_NodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] Coordinates = Road_Vertices_NodeList[i].InnerText.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
            Roads_Vertices[i, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(Coordinates[0]);
            Roads_Vertices[i, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(Coordinates[1]);
        }

        XmlNodeList Road_Segments_NodeList = Road_File.GetElementsByTagName("Road_Segment");
        for (int i = 0; i < Road_Segments_NodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] Coordinates = Road_Segments_NodeList[i].InnerText.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
            Roads_Segments[i, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(Coordinates[0]);
            Roads_Segments[i, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(Coordinates[1]);
            // Readall the rest of the data
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have declared the *size* of `Roads_Vertices` and `Roads_Segments`. Is there some code missing?

Comment: What does a debugger show? To answer this we really need to see the XML document. And please reduce to a minimum sample (eg. second loop occurs after error so that can go).

Comment: Roads_Vertices and Roads_Segments have not been initiated.

Comment: Don't add thanks as an answer. Add it as one or more comments to each answer, or just a thanks at the top. The best way to say thanks is by upvoting relevant answers and accepting the best answer. Also, use the same account always. (your answer below seems to be entered with a different account since the rep value doesn't match..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not initialize the static array:

```
Roads_Vertices = new double[Road_Vertices_NodeList.Count,2];
```

Static means it can be accessed without an instance of the type it is enclosed by, or by static methods inside it, but not that it does not have to be initialized.

Trying to say it in english:

There will be a Road_Vertices that will be static and a double multidimensional array:

```
static double[,] Roads_Vertices; // declaration
```

And here it is, as big as it matters:

```
 Roads_Vertices = new double[Road_Vertices_NodeList.Count,2]; // definition
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize `Road_Vertices` and `Road_Segment`.  you have only declared them, you have not assigned a value to the variables.

you need to do something like:

```
static double[,] Roads_Vertices=new double[someValue,someOtherValue];
```